# How to match attribute for special character in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Assume that I have xml as follow and I want to match the template for 
tag **Cell** with attribute **aid5:cellstyle="hilite_white"**

How can I do that in XSLT template as I can't select attribute with special char like **:**?

```
<table>
<Cell aid:table="cell" aid5:cellstyle="hilite_white" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="112" />
</table>
```

@jim: here is what I try

```
<xsl:template match="Cell[@aid5:cellstyle='hilite_white']">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />

        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: And what error did you get? PLEASE READ THE [FAQ] and [Ask] before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `*` as the namespace prefix in your match:

```
match="Cell[@*:cellstyle='hilite_white']"
```

or you can declare the prefix in your `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:aid5="unknown namespace uri" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

(Replace `unknown namespace uri` with whatever the namepace uri is in the source XML.)